# How do I save an SVG written in HTML as an SVG file?

Tags: svg

The following SVG code is written in an HTML file. But how do I save it as an SVG image?

```xml
<!-- code written in an HTML file -->
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<defs>
<linearGradient id="fill" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(224,224,224);stop-opacity:1"/>
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(153,153,153);stop-opacity:1"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>

<path d="M 0 0 L 64 0 L 32 64 z" stroke="colourname" fill="url(#fill)"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Just put it in a file, what's the problem you are seeing?

Comment: If I put it in a file it's ok, but I would like to use it as a border-image property as in: img.frame {
-moz-border-image: url('frame.svg') 93 92 87 92;
}

Comment: Well it has to be somehow saved? Or does it go only one way i.e. from image to svn html?

Comment: I see, you meant text file not html document. The minuses helped :) to review answers.

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS3? SVG is not directly related to CSS.

Comment: check this website: https://nikitahl.github.io/svg-2-code/

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Just had to save it in a text file and give it a .svg extension.

Comment: Also make sure to add xml tag a the top of the svg file just before pasting the svg tag
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: @Kiarash In Office365 adding the xml tag makes the svg unrecognizable.

Comment: for me xml tag was not necessary, but I had to remove any <br>

Comment: Don't forget: xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

Comment: Indeed for me the key was to add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` (don't forget t include the `http://www.` part - this tripped me up when I copied & pasted the value from @GBrian).

Comment: Adding `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` to the <svg> tag works. Without this, the SVG is broken.

Comment: And everyone remember to make sure all variables are surrounded with inverted commas! HTML doesn't seem to mind their absence but its crucial for SVG code.