# Google Email Image broken

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

I have sent the email from my project when user signup. In email have the logo of my company but the image shows the broken image but when the load image link separate it's working.

```
<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/XySHurPE69idjp9H2VjVyhzxTOXiry4kY7oZkVN1wOVakk872Xu-QTyEiNFYnmP5jfzzZP6grxPTv3X1HzHhpJSLqx_70gTHIGLpNsehoTAWyOkT1EU0MoY6=s0-d-e1-ft#https://hep-ara-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/391655img1565690972.svg" class="m_-4882676647199407500ara-logo CToWUd" style="display:inline-block;margin:20px 15px;width:100px" alt="ara-logo">
```

above code is come form email template. Image not loaded.
Add some URL in front of given image URL -https://hep-ara-dev.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/391655img1565690972.svg**strong text**

Comment: Please provide some code of how you're referencing the image in your email, the name of the image that you're using and where you're referencing it from. Your above request doesn't provide anything that would allow us to give an answer for your issue

Comment: @Jenko check now question.pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question needs closing as duplicate, question regarding SVG images used in HTML emails has been answered here: [How can I embed SVG into HTML in an email, so that it's visible in most/all email browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753911/how-can-i-embed-svg-into-html-in-an-email-so-that-its-visible-in-most-all-emai)

In a nutshell, SVG file types are not supported by all email platforms.